# Clang-Tidy can't find my header files

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

new to clang and clang-tidy here.

I have a project with this type of structure:

`project/
 - build/
 - cmake/
 - component1/
    - src/
       - someFile.cpp
       - someFile2.cpp
    - someFile.hpp
    - someFile2.hpp
 - component2/
 - etc...
 -`

When I use clang-tidy to go through all the files in `project/component1/` with this command: `clang-tidy project/component1/src/* -checks=-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-alpha*`

It ends up throwing an error like this:

`$HOME/project/component1/src/someFile.cpp:18:10: error: 'project/component1/someFile.hpp' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
\#include "component1/someFile.hpp"`

Comment: Could it be that they are not in the same level ('someFile.hpp' is not in /src)?

Comment: @Grif-fin I've thought of that, but I'm not allowed to mess with the file structure. Is there are command options that I can set to let it know where the *.hpp files are?

The descriptions of each option are not always high-level enough for me to get what's going on. *:-/

Comment: I just tried running the clang-tidy command on the `project/component1/` directory but I'm getting the same error or those files under `src/`.

Comment: You could try with flag --header-filter=<path_to_component1> or include the hpp files in cpp with '../'. e.g. #include "../someFile.hpp". The later option is not recommended.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This answer will only help you if you use CMake to manage your project.

CMake has an option to create a .json file that contains all the compiler calls with command line options. This file can be given to clang-tidy with the option:

```
-p <build-path> is used to read a compile command database.

    For example, it can be a CMake build directory in which a file named
    compile_commands.json exists (use -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
    CMake option to get this output). When no build path is specified,
    a search for compile_commands.json will be attempted through all
    parent paths of the first input file . See:
    http://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html for an
    example of setting up Clang Tooling on a source tree.
```

As the documentation states, you have to set the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` variable to generate the .json file with CMake and then pass the CMake output directory to clang-tidy.
Clang-tidy will then get the include paths from the commands in the .json file.

Comment: This is unnecessary if you are using CMake. You can just use `set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy)` and it [will add the full command line to `clang-tidy` itself.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html#prop_tgt:%3CLANG%3E_CLANG_TIDY).

Answer (score 36):

I tell clang-tidy to search for them using plain compiler includes, but they have to be introduced after a double dash (--). It also took me a while to discover it, since it is not included in the `--help`:

```
clang-tidy -checks='...' <source0> ... -- -Iblabla/ ...
```

Reading again the options, you coult try `-extra-arg=` parameter, but I use the double dash approax since it allows me to put all the options to give clang and clang-tidy in a single file, with no more processing than a `$(cat $file)` for both.

---

From: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#using-clang-tidy

> clang-tidy is a LibTooling-based tool . You can also specify compilation options on the command line after --

Comment: This answer is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in CMake. The problem in my case was that Clang-Tidy could not handle include directories via response files – at least in version 10.

Deactivating them solved it:

```
# Disable response files
set(CMAKE_CXX_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_INCLUDES Off)
```