# clang-tidy errors with file not found when using CMake interface targets and compilation database

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy

## Overview

I am trying to run [clang-tidy](/questions/tagged/clang-tidy) against my [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) codebase, which is built using [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake).

I am generating a compilation database as part of the build and passing this via the `-p` flag to `clang-tidy` - however, `clang-tidy` complains with `error: 'static_1.h' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]` . This causes `clang-tidy` to exit with status 2, which fails my build.

I would like `clang-tidy` to be able to find all header files that are used as part of the build - ideally without using any additional tools other than CMake, or changing any `INTERFACE` targets to `STATIC` or `SHARED`.

## Details

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── ignored
│   ├── include
│   │   └── ignored.h
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── ignored.cpp
├── interface_1
│   ├── include
│   │   └── interface_1.h
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── static_1
│   ├── include
│   │   └── static_1.h
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── static_1.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

And my CMake configuration looks like this:
[image: a CMake build graph showing that example is the top-level executable, which is linked privately to interface_1 (which is an interface target), which is linked via interface to static_1 (which is a static target). There is also the static target ignored, which is not linked to anything.]

When I build the project using the following commands:

```bash
$ mkdir build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Unix Makefiles" -S . -B build
$ cd build
$ cmake --build . -- -j
```

The project compiles successfully, and there is the following `compile_commands.json` file inside `build`:

```json
[
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/interface_1/include -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build/ignored",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/ignored/include -g -o CMakeFiles/ignored.dir/ignored.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/ignored/ignored.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/ignored/ignored.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build/static_1",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/static_1.dir/static_1.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp"
}
]
```

However, when I run `clang-tidy`:

```bash
$ clang-tidy -p build main.cpp static_1/include/static_1.h static_1/static_1.cpp interface_1/include/interface_1.h
```

I get the following error:

```
/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/interface_1/include/interface_1.h:4:10: error: 'static_1.h' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include <static_1.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

## Minimal example

### Root directory

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.1)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

project(example)

add_subdirectory(ignored)
add_subdirectory(interface_1)
add_subdirectory(static_1)

add_executable(example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE interface_1)
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <interface_1.h>

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

### static_1

```
# static_1/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(static_1 STATIC static_1.cpp)
target_include_directories(static_1 PUBLIC include)
```

```cpp
// static_1/static_1.cpp
#include <static_1.h>
```

```cpp
// static_1/include/static_1.h
#ifndef STATIC_1_H
#define STATIC_1_H
#endif // STATIC_1_H
```

### interface_1

```
# interface_1/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(interface_1 INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(interface_1 INTERFACE include)
target_link_libraries(interface_1 INTERFACE static_1)
```

```cpp
// interface_1/include/interface_1.h
#ifndef INTERFACE_1_H
#define INTERFACE_1_H
#include <static_1.h>
#endif // INTERFACE_1_H
```

### ignored

```
# ignored/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(ignored STATIC ignored.cpp)
target_include_directories(ignored PUBLIC include)
```

```cpp
// ignored/ignored.cpp
#include <ignored.h>
```

```cpp
// ignored/include/ignored.h
#ifndef IGNORED_H
#define IGNORED_H
#endif // IGNORED_H
```

## What did I find / try?

I have found a few links that are along similar lines, but not exactly the same as my question:

- [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455090/clang-tidy-cant-find-my-header-files) suggest:

  - using plain compiler includes, which does work - but I don't want to have to manually configure `clang-tidy` for this, I want it to derive the files automatically
  - using a compilation database, which I am already doing
  - disabling response files, which I tried but there was no change in output
- [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261868/getting-clang-tidy-to-fix-header-files) suggest:

  - using `--header-filter` - I tried `--header-filter="*.h"` with no effect

I also found these issues / MRs. They seem slightly related but I'm not sure they are the cause of the issue:

- [Headers files inside compile_commands.json](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16285)
- [Add target to verify that all headers in header sets can be compiled independently](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23338)

I have also found the tool [compdb](https://github.com/Sarcasm/compdb), which seems designed for this purpose. However, if possible, I would like to find a solution that only uses CMake, as I'm relying on the dependencies for my project being already packaged in Debian.

## The confusing case of the `ignored` target

For extra information - I noticed the following, which unfortunately confused me even more.

### Remove `ignored` target

There is the `ignored` folder above - when I delete this folder, the error disappears. Additionally, the compilation database becomes:

```json
[
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/interface_1/include -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build/static_1",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/static_1.dir/static_1.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp"
}
]
```

### Rename `ignored` target

Additionally, if I rename `ignored` to `not_used` throughout the codebase, the error also disappears.

```json
[
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/interface_1/include -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build/not_used",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/not_used/include -g -o CMakeFiles/not_used.dir/not_used.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/not_used/not_used.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/not_used/not_used.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build/static_1",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/static_1.dir/static_1.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp"
}
]
```

### Make `ignored` an `INTERFACE` target

Finally, if I remove `ignored.cpp` and turn `ignored` into an `INTERFACE` target, the error also disappears.

```json
[
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/interface_1/include -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/main.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/build/static_1",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/include -g -o CMakeFiles/static_1.dir/static_1.cpp.o -c /tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/tmp.XkimKdDJyo/clang-tidy-so-issue/static_1/static_1.cpp"
}
]
```

I presume these are all the results of interactions with the compilation database. However, I'm confused how this interaction would remove the error.

## Versions

I am using the following versions:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
cmake version 3.25.1
g++ (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0
Debian LLVM version 14.0.6 # (clang-tidy)
```

Comment: Very well-written question!  I think the problem is you are passing `interface_1.h` on the `clang-tidy` command line.  Since that file doesn't match anything in the compilation database, `clang-tidy` does not know what flags to use for it.  Normally, you only pass the names of top-level source files (the `.cpp` files) to `clang-tidy`, and the headers get checked indirectly due to being included.  Is there a specific reason for also passing the headers explicitly?

Comment: note: CMake has clang-tidy support built-in: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html

Comment: Thanks both for your help. I tried with only the source files and this did work, although on experimenting I can create situations where an included header will not get checked by clang-tidy. I need more time to investigate this though, so @ScottMcPeak if you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for the "file not found" error is you are passing the
name of a header file directly on the `clang-tidy` command line.

That does not work because the file names passed to `clang-tidy` are
looked up in `compile_commands.json`, but only top-level source files
(`.cpp` files) have entries in that file.  Since the header file is not
found in the compilation database, `clang-tidy` does not use any `-I`
flags, and consequently cannot find the things that header includes.

Instead, only pass the top-level file names to `clang-tidy`, which will
also check the files that are included by it, transitively.

You've indicated (in a comment) that `clang-tidy` seems to be failing to
report some issues in headers when it is used that way.  Various
checkers have heuristics and options regarding when to report things in
header files, and that might be playing a role.  You could ask a
follow-up question with a specific instance in which this is happening.

Side note: When I reproduced the problem using your files, I found that
`cmake` (version 3.15.3 in my case) did not generate a
`compile_commands.json` file.
Following [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66560758/2659307) at
[CMake not generating compile_commands.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960835/cmake-not-generating-compile-commands-json),
I changed the operative line to:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

and that worked.  I mention this because, with the original line,
`cmake` might not be consistently regenerating `compile_commands.json`,
which could interfere with experimentation and diagnosis.  (You already
mentioned a mystery involving the `ignored` target, so perhaps that is
related.)